# i can't get the avatar of roblox in cheerio module

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, node-modules, roblox, cheerio

**I can't return the element using the cheerio module, when i return the children .avatar-card-image element, some of the elements are not visible.**

*I tried doing $('img .ng-isolate-scope').attr('src') but it don't work idk why bruh*

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const request = require('request')
function fetchUser(username) {
    var user = username
    const api = "https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username="
    let apiID = api + user
    return fetch(apiID)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((function(data) {
        var ID = null
        if (data['Id']) {
            ID = data['Id']
        } else if (data['success'] === false) {
            ID = data['errorMessage']
        }
        return ID
    }))
}


function getInfoUser(id) {
    var info = 
    {
        nickname: null,
        username: null,
        avatar: null
    }

    request({method: 'GET', url: 'https://www.roblox.com/users/' + id +'/profile'}, function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) return console.log(err)

        $ = cheerio.load(body)
        const header = $('.header-title')
        const names = $('.header-names')
        const avatar = $('img .ng-isolate-scope')
        info.nickname = names.find('.profile-display-name').text().replace(/\s/g, '')
        info.username = header.find('.font-header-1').text().replace(/\s/g, '')
        info.avatar = avatar.html()
        console.log(info)

        const div = $('.avatar-headshot-lg').children('.avatar-card-link').children('.avatar-card-image').html()
        console.log(div)
    })
}


fetchUser('Stephan_chan').then((result) => getInfoUser(result))
```

> Output: [image: https://i.imgur.com/n8xtQHi.png]

Answer (score 0):

this is an html DOM generated by JS so cheerio does not see it unless you first execute an html page in JS-enabled browser.

Otherwise, your best bet is to extract `<meta property="og:image">`:

```
// define function which accepts body and cheerio as args
function extract(input, cheerio) {
    // return object with extracted values              
    let $ = cheerio.load(input);
    return {
        img: $('meta[property=og:image]', this).attr('content')
    };
}
```

Proof of work (screenshot):
[image: proof of work (screenshot)]